# Append Rows to existing table in Big Query using the Web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I used to be able to append rows to an existing table in Big Query using the Google's Big Query Web UI. I used to use the 'load job' to append rows to an existing table. However now the 'load job' has only the 'create table' interface. Is there any way to use the Big Query UI to do this? I do understand I can use the bq interface to achieve the same.

Answer (score 11):

I believe, this is just matter of bad wording
In reality, if you provide existing table - it will append rows into existing table vs. create new one, even though the button is still saying <kbd>Create Table</kbd>